How to update composer packages on plesk
I see there are updates available in Plesk / Composer

But if I click Install or Update nothing changes. I try to understand the columns "Version" and "Update". They make no sense to me.

Perhaps the problem lies in the settings or access permissions.
Point number two: isn't it the other way around?
In the "Version" column, your current version is shown, and in the "Update" column—the available one. In your case, that would be a downgrade.
But if you really want to, you can try via SSH using the command composer update.

Why would an update show a downgrade?
